# How does the child process not leave the while loop after the first message is read?

Tags: c, linux, while-loop, pipe

I recently came across this example in trying to solve my own pipe question in Linux C, which did answer my question, but gave me another question, why doesn't the child process leave the while loop after the first message? If it has already read the input message to completion, wouldn't it just leave before the parent has a chance to input the second message after the sleep(5)?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/ioctl.h>

    int main()
    {
        int pid = 0;

        // create pipe pair
        int fd[2];
        pipe(fd);

        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0)
        {
            // child side
            char *buff = NULL;
            char byte = 0;
            int count = 0;

            // close write side. don't need it.
            close(fd[1]);

            // read at least one byte from the pipe.
            while (read(fd[0], &byte, 1) == 1)
            {
                if (ioctl(fd[0], FIONREAD, &count) != -1)
                {
                    fprintf(stdout,"Child: count = %d\n",count);

                    // allocate space for the byte we just read + the rest
                    //  of whatever is on the pipe.
                    buff = malloc(count+1);
                    buff[0] = byte;
                    if (read(fd[0], buff+1, count) == count)
                        fprintf(stdout,"Child: received \"%s\"\n", buff);
                    free(buff);
                }
                else
                {   // could not read in-size
                    perror("Failed to read input size.");
                }
            }

            // close our side
            close(fd[0]);
            fprintf(stdout,"Child: Shutting down.\n");
        }
        else
        {   // close read size. don't need it.
            const char msg1[] = "Message From Parent";
            const char msg2[] = "Another Message From Parent";
            close(fd[0]);
            fprintf(stdout, "Parent: sending \"%s\"\n", msg1);
            write(fd[1], msg1, sizeof(msg1));
            sleep(5); // simulate process wait
            fprintf(stdout, "Parent: sending \"%s\"\n", msg2);
            write(fd[1], msg2, sizeof(msg2));
            close(fd[1]);
            fprintf(stdout,"Parent: Shutting down.\n");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You might want to read the manpage for `read()`

Comment: The only time `read()` will return something other than `1` is when the parent closes the pipe or there's an error. Why would the loop end before that?

Comment: If the parent hasn't sent a message, `read()` will block until there's something to read.

Comment: You shouldn't use `ioctl(fd[0], FIONREAD, &count)` to separate messages. Instead, your protocol should have a built-in means of isolating messages (e.g. by length-prefixing them or by using a sentinel value to delimit them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read` blocks until data arrives if no data is available (unless the pipe was made non-blocking).

Comment: Oh okay! So if the parent updates the write end, the read end goes over the new message again, and we can do this as many times until the parent process closes the pipe?

Comment: Yes. . . . . . .